# Is there an easy way to view SVN changes in the OpenOffice/LibreOffice document compare view?

Tags: linux, svn, libreoffice

I store documents in a subversion repository. I would like to be able to see either my local yet to be checked-in modifications, or else the differences between two particular revisions, using the LibreOffice document compare function.

Currently I have to manually check out the old version without changes and then choose the two files, by going to Edit>Compare Document.

Ideally this would be a single command line or else some kind of extension that would let me view the SVN revision history within LibreOffice Writer.